# php foreach loop issue in IE11

Tags: php, wordpress, internet-explorer, foreach

I have very weird issue with php foreach loop in IE 11. In FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 7 8 9 10 Foreach loop works fine.

I used for() loop for dummy text it works fine in IE 11. But i don't know how to call arrays in for or while loop

here is my code.

```
$img_num4 = 4;
$data_chunks = array_chunk($wp_images, $num_img);

echo '<ul id="id1">';
    foreach ($data_chunks as $data_chunk) {
        echo '<li class="id2">';
        foreach($data_chunk as $data) {
                    if($data['image_links_to'])
                        echo '<a href="'.$data['image_links_to'].'" '.$new_window.'>';
                    echo '<img src="'.$data['file_url'].'" class="logo-img" alt="" />';
                    if($data['image_links_to'])
                    echo '</a>';
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
echo '</ul>';
```

I don't know why foreach loop not working in IE 11 only. Any Suggestions.

I also try this:

```
$img_num4 = 4;
$data_chunks = array_chunk($wp_images, $num_img);

echo '<ul id="id1">';
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
            echo '<li>'.$i.'</li>';
        }
    /*foreach ($data_chunks as $data_chunk) {
        echo '<li class="slide">';
        foreach($data_chunk as $data) {
                    if($data['image_links_to'])
                        echo '<a href="'.$data['image_links_to'].'" '.$new_window.'>';
                    echo '<img src="'.$data['file_url'].'" class="logo-img" alt="" />';
                    if($data['image_links_to'])
                    echo '</a>';
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }*/
echo '</ul>';
```

It shows me correct data in IE 11. But foreach loop not work

please tell me how can i call arrays in for or while loop

Comment: foreach has nothing to do with IE check your styles for the elements.

Comment: bro it works in IE 8,9,10 -- i don't get the issue icheck everthing

Comment: PHP is processed on the server... Check your html and styling, that will be the issue.

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't work'? This `foreach` loop will print out the same HTML regardless of browser. Is it possible `$new_window` has some characters it shouldn't have (eg '<' or '>') - if it does it could just be that Chrome, FF, etc are just dealing with the malformed HTML better. Try going to 'View Source' on your web browser to see what the loop is printing out. x

Comment: Not a PHP issue! Check the source in your IE11 to confirm all the list items are there and fix the HTML/CSS for IE11.

Comment: I think @EmilyShepherd was asking HOW it doesn't work. No way to know what the problem might be without knowing HOW it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a for loop it should be like :

```
$img_num4 = 4;
$data_chunks = array_chunk($wp_images, $num_img);

echo '<ul id="id1">';
$len = $data_chunks.lenght;
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $data_chunk = $data_chunks[$i];
    echo '<li class="id2">';
    $len2 = $data_chunk.lenght;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $len2; $j++) {
        $data = $data_chunk[$j];
        if($data['image_links_to']) {
            echo '<a href="'.$data['image_links_to'].'" '.$new_window.'>';
        }
        echo '<img src="'.$data['file_url'].'" class="logo-img" alt="" />';
        if($data['image_links_to']) {
            echo '</a>';
        }
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

a while loop is not so useful here.

As metionned in comments, php's an html preprocessor so it does not need any browser to work. Maybe you should look on the html source in your IE11 browser to see what is buggy.

MAYBE (and that's an important part of the sentence) IE11 doesn't display `<li>` if it does not contains any text. Here you only put an `<img>` (sometimes with a link).

You should try replacing img tag with text in your foreach loop.

Apolo

Comment: $data_chunks is array, so .lenght is correct for array

Comment: It means that it is not the foreach that is buggy with IE11, because my code do exactly the same as the initial code. :/

Comment: See the and of my answer (starting with MAYBE) ;-)

Comment: what about the html source code ? is it ok ? (I mean, like you wanted it to be)

Comment: ok i got it there is a condition that check the browser engine and i use "MSIE" that is for old version and now i put "rv:11.0" in condiotion also......thanx for help